# do free template functions need to be static and inlined?

Tags: c++, templates

Given this code

```cpp
// In header file
template<typename T>
inline static void my_func(T var)
{
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

// Used in many cpp files:
void some_function()
{
    my_func(1);
    my_func("test");
}
```

I just "upgraded" my free function to a template. It was static and inlined before. But now its a template, I am not 100% if inline and static still apply - my guess is they do... but I am not 100% about the template generation mechanics (i.e. does it copy/paste it into each translation unit?)

Comment: If you want internal linkage, you will still require the `static` keyword.

Comment: Having a `static` function in a header file is a little weird.  function template are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All function templates are `inline` by default, so that keyword isn't needed.

The `static` keyword was likely unnecessary before you converted `my_func` to be a template, and likely still is.  Marking a free function `static` gives its name internal linkage, but since it's declared in a header that doesn't accomplish much here.  Any translation unit can simply `#include` your header and have access to the function anyway.  `static` functions are much more useful in .cpp files, where it serves to essentially mark the function as internal and prevent other translation units from calling it.

Comment: ah, that part about template are inlined by default was what I was missing - thankyou :)